# roslibjs subscribe to sensor_msgs/image

Tags: ros, sensor-msgs, 2d-image, roslibjs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I couldn't find an example of how to subscribe to a sensor_msgs/image and display it in a html5 canvas. I already have a page running and I can somehow access the data, but it won't display in an image nor in a html5 canvas. This is an excerpt of my test code:

```
imageTopic.subscribe(function(message)
{
   var imagedata = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + message.data;
   document.getElementById('xy_image').setAttribute('src', imagedata);
   imageTopic.unsubscribe();
});
```

First of all: how can I access the frames without subscribing to the topic every time and unsubscribing to it again? Second: The message.data seems correct, but the header doesnt work and the image is not displayed. I tried png as well, with no success. I would be happy if you could help me out - maybe with a basic example.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252548/roslibjs-subscribe-to-sensor_msgs/image/) by [Swoncen](https://answers.ros.org/users/26982/swoncen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-01-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found a solution:

```
var imageTopic = new ROSLIB.Topic({
    ros : ros,
    name : '/camera/image/compressed',
    messageType : 'sensor_msgs/CompressedImage'
});
```

the compressed image can be retrieved via:

```
var imagedata = "data:image/jpg;base64," + message.data;
```

---

Originally posted by [Swoncen](https://answers.ros.org/users/26982/swoncen/) with karma: 23 on 2017-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-22**:
I've converted your comment to an answer, as it would seem you have answered your own question (good!).

Could you accept your own answer? You can do so by ticking the checkmark to the left of the answer.